Unexpected Types in Pycharm on less than function w/ Data class and Total Ordering
I have a simple data class (really just tuples but I wanted them named) and Pycharm is giving me a unexpected type warning on it and I'm not sure why. More out of curiosity since this does work. Version is 3.13 for python and 2024.2.4 for Pycharm.
Code
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import total_ordering
from typing import Self

@total_ordering
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class NumMatch:
    position: int
    value: str

    def __lt__(self, other: Self) -> bool:
        return (self.position, self.value) < (other.position, other.value)

Warning:
Expected type 'tuple[int, ...]' (matched generic type 'tuple[_T_co, ...]'), got 'tuple[int, str]' instead
Any ideas? The "got" is what I thought expected would be (an int, str tuple). The expected is weird.

With the appropriate imports added, mypy reports no issues. This looks like a Pycharm problem.
